# Why toLocaleString() method does not effect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Is there any way to use `toLocaleString()` method in nativescript?
Please check [toLocaleString - {N} Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=w6DXbt)

```html
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                trDate: new Date(1579180347000).toLocaleString("tr"), 
                // should print 16.01.2020 16:12:27

            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

[Browser compatibility docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility) says :

[image: nodejs]

Does it means that I better use some other package such as [date-and-time](https://yarnpkg.com/package/date-and-time) to manage **date data format** ?

Comment: **{N} !== NodeJS**, NativeScript just has a JavaScript runtime, only CommonJS modules work with it. Anything that depends on browser / node specific features, can't be used. You may try momentjs, it has a wide range of locale support.

Comment: Could you please write your answer in **an answer** form? I think it's important to know [commonJs {N} relation.](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/commonjs-modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**{N} !== NodeJS**

NativeScript just has a JavaScript runtime, only CommonJS modules work with it. Anything that depends on browser / node specific features, can't be used. You may try momentjs, it has a wide range of locale support.

Comment: Recommended reading for readers; [nativescript core concepts](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/getting-started/modules)

Answer (score 1):

```
data() {
  return {
   trDate: new Date(1579180347000).toLocaleString("tr"),
  }
 }
```

maybe i'm silly, but you haven't mentioned your error this won't return a string but an object. can you please try

> new Date(1579180347000).toLocaleString("tr-TR")

just to make sure it's not the problem.

also, in such scenarios what u should use is the computed not data.

```
  computed: {
    trDate: function () {
      return new Date(1579180347000).toLocaleString("tr-TR");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried; NO. computed  trDate also failed. It's clear that  **Anything that depends on browser / node specific features, can't be used**
(https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=w6DXbt&v=4)

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is nodejs version because I have the same case on DigitalOcean auto-deploy feature.

I've solved it with **engines** property in package.json

```
{   
  "engines": {
    "node":">=15" 
  }
}
```

[more info about package.json - engines](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#engines)

Answer (score 0):

As per [@Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060423/manoj) answer **{N} !== NodeJS** so to get it working you'll need to install **[Intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl)** to your project knowing that `toLocaleString` is using `Intl`.

```
npm i intl
```

References:

1. [**tolocalstring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)
2. [**Intl**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)